# search for a string in docker logs in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, logging, grep, findstr

On Linux i used to fire this command

```
docker logs wp-mysql 2>&1 | grep "ready for connections"
```

However, I wish to search for the string on Windows

I tried the below two attempts but it shows not just the searched lines but also a few extra lines which I do not need.

```
docker logs wp-mysql 2>&1 | findstr "ready for connections"
```

and

```
docker logs wp-mysql 2> >(findstr 'ready for connections')
```

Can you please suggest a grep alternative for searching string in docker logs on Windows please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How *findstr* works

This command searches for any of the strings "ready", "for" or "connections":

```
findstr "ready for connections"
```

This command searches for the string "ready for connections":

```
findstr /C:"ready for connections"
```

#### Solution

This command should solve your problems:

```
docker logs wp-mysql 2>&1 | findstr /C:"ready for connections"
```

#### Alternative solution

Or this one, provided the native windows command *find* is the first one found in your path, the default install location is in C:\Windows\System32, but some people prefer to put the path to the unix *find* command before the build-in windows *find* command:

```
docker logs wp-mysql 2>&1 | find "ready for connections"
```

#### Info

Use the option /? to show how to use a windows command line utility. Look at the ouput of these two commands:

```
findstr /?
find /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a practical example of usage.

Here is an example together with Docker logs. I have running a Docker container with container id starting with 42. I want to see why the Docker container fails at start. It tries to connect to Mongoose DB and container fails. I redirect the output and I use select-string to achieve this.

First I run this command :

```
docker logs 42 2>&1 | select-string -pattern "Error" | select LineNumber,Line
```

This then gives me both the LineNumber and the Line, so I can see where in the output I have the pattern with text "Error".

```
LineNumber Line
---------- ----
         1 connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
        31     compatibilityError: null,
        42 MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
        66         error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
        68           name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        86     compatibilityError: null,
```

You can use this on similar streams such as strings and files that are string based in Powershell.